# Django tests: Don't close selenium driver after each test

Tags: django, selenium, functional-testing

I have a test suite that includes a lot of tests for `selenium`. Now, I have a lot of tests, and they take quite a while, so I am trying to speed up the process.

Part of the issue is that it takes quite some time for selenium to close and reopen firefox between each test. I don't see why it should either. I realise that we don't want things like login sessions to carry over between tests, but say we had a way of clearing it.

So, before any tests run, I want a driver to open firefox. All tests use this driver, and sessions are cleared between each test. After all tests have finished, the driver should close.

I am not sure how to accomplish this. I have initialized the driver in a file that all tests import, which will successfully keep the window open, but I don't know how to close it when tests have finished.

Are the some way to capture `test_start` and `test_end` events or something? I havn't been able to find documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping a single Selenium driver across multiple tests is a kind of global state. The entity responsible for setting up and tearing down the global state is the test runner. You could do it this way:

1. Have your utility library export a function like `get_driver()` which starts a driver if no driver was started or returns the already existing driver.
2. I presume that you have some tests (e.g. model tests) that don't need Selenium. Have the tests that do need a driver call `get_driver()`. (This does not need to be test by test. If all the tests in a test class need a driver then `setUp` could make one call.) This way a driver is not started for tests that don't need it.
3. Have a custom test runner tell the utility library to close any driver that it may have running.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#defining-a-test-runner) is the documentation about defining a new test runner.

Comment: That is an excellent answer. The documentation you link to is plenty to fix my issue. Thanks buddy